# Installing Appium server on Windows -- how to get past grunt errors?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, appium

I'm using this guide:

https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/running-on-windows.md

And on this step:

```
grunt configAndroidBootstrap
```

I can't get it to run. I've tried:

1. Running it inside node.
2. `GitHub\appium\node_modules\.bin\grunt.cmd` configAndroidBootstrap

Running `\appium\node_modules\.bin\grunt.cmd` by itself works, it does something at least. But when I add the configAndroid.. part it does:

```
Running "configAndroidBootstrap" task
The system cannot find the path specified.
Warning: Task "configAndroidBootstrap" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options.

1.) Install pre-built Appium for Windows (no grunting required)(https://bitbucket.org/appium/appium.app/downloads/AppiumForWindows.zip)

2.) Run reset.bat instead of the grunt commands. I've updated the doc you referenced to mention that.

Comment: I ended up downloading an outdated version of appium from that link. Many wasted hours figuring out subsequent issues that were caused. As of today the latest Appium is v0.8.0